# No selenium tests run during mvn integration test

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test my web app with Selenium ,integrate the test classes with maven. When I give command mvn integration-test, The test class is recognised, but the tests are not being executed. In the end, The build is successfull.

```
     Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.228 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.915s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 11 20:15:59 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------
```

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Music</groupId>
    <artifactId>Music</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>5.10</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>user</name>
                            <value>tobrien</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>name</name>
                            <value>Tim O'Brien</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <background>true</background>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Test code:

```
public class FunctionalTest {
private Selenium selenium;

      @BeforeClass
      public void startSelenium() {
        this.selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 8080, "*chrome",
            "http://www.twitter.com");
        this.selenium.start();
      }
@Test
      @Parameters( { "user", "name" })
      public void testTwitter(String user, String name) {
        try {
          selenium.open("http://www.twitter.com/" + user);
          selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");
          assert selenium.isTextPresent(name);

        } catch (SeleniumException e) {
          throw e;
        }
      }
@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
      public void stopSelenium() {
        this.selenium.stop();
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some test code?

Comment: Why do you have `skip` set?

Comment: I just followed the pom.xml file given in http://books.sonatype.com/mcookbook/reference/ch08s02.html site

Answer (score 0):

You have the skip tests tag added in the configuration of the maven surefire plugin

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            ...
         </plugin>
```

this configuration will skip maven running the tests for all phases bellow "pre-integration-test phase". Try and set this value to false or remove it completely.

Answer (score 0):

**By default the maven-surefire-plugin is only running during test phase. You need to enable it by adding an additional execution, which is running at integration-test phase.** Here is a best practice, where normal tests are named *Test.java and integration tests are named *IT.java:

```xml
<!-- Integration tests -->
<!-- Exclude *IT.java at test phase -->
<!-- Include *IT.java at integration-test phase, but exclude normal tests -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>integration-test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>integration-test</phase>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*IT.java</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Add a configuration to the maven-surefire-plugin to exclude tests, which end with "*IT.java" to avoid the execution of integration tests during test phase. Then add an execution for the integration tests, that is running on integration-test phase. To override the shared plugin configuration, which is used for the test phase execution, specify a configuration within the integration-test execution. This configuration includes integration tests ("*IT.java") and excludes normal tests ("*Test.java"), because in the integration-test phase only integration tests should run. The normal tests will still run once within the test phase, but not again in the integration-test phase.